# how to get picture size when reading from a excel file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, xlsx

I am converting excel (xls, xlsx) file to html. But when image is there I am not able to get image size(dimention) which is there in the excel file. I am using apache poi.
How to get image size of that file? Please help me on that.

Comment: What size are you after? Size of the image in bytes? Native size in pixels of the image? Scaled size as shown in Excel in some units? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This source explains how to get picture data from the excel file: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images.

Within the loop there is a

```
 byte[] data = pict.getData();
```

You can use that byte array, write it to a ByteArrayOutputStream object and call the size() method to retrieve the size of the file written to the outputstream.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 baos.write(data);
 int fileSizeInBytes = baos.size();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This just returns the total byte size of the image. To get the dimensions you would need to figure out the image type and then decode the image header from the byte array.

Comment: Oh, I thought he was trying to find out the file size of the picture, not the dimensions. My apologies.

Comment: yes Michael I am trying to get dimention of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an overkill, but you can create an image from the byte array and check its size. For example:

```
for (HSSFPictureData pic : workbook.getAllPictures()) {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(pic.getData());
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    System.out.println(image.getWidth() + ":" + image.getHeight());
}
```